# read input data gzipped file line by line

Tags: c++

I am acquainted that some folks have already written about this question; however, this question is not clear to me yet. I need to read gzipped files which contain unformatted data. I have unsuccessfully tried following instructions from zlib and gzstream sites. Could anybody provide me a quick example of how to extract data directly from the compressed gzip file using an ifstream? My procedure using dat files is the following:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>

int main () {
    ifstream file;
    string stringtemp;
    stringstream line2convert;
    file.open("directory/file.dat");
    // read each line using a for loop (I know the total number of lines)
    file.getline (line,100);
    // extract information line by line using stringstreams
    line2convert  << line;
    line2convert >> int2convert;   
    ...
    ...
    ...
}
```

Anybody could give me a hint to add a few lines that I need?

Thanks!
 - F

Comment: Where are you trying to read a gzipped file? It looks like standard non-compressed file input to me.

Comment: @Brendan, I believe s/he has working code already and wishes to extend it to transparently support reading zlib compressed files.

Comment: Yes, exactly. This code works and I want to extend it to support reading zlib files.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if you know how to link in gzstream, you can do that

just replace "ifstream" with "igzstream"

.

Comment: I did that change in my code. Right now I am trying to link in gzstream. I follow its documentation step by step (http://www.cs.unc.edu/Research/compgeom/gzstream/#inst), but I got some problems when they say "Either compile gzstream.C by hand, place it in some library, and move gzstream.h into the include ... ". I do not know where I should move the file gzstream.C. In my computer, I copied gzstream.h to /usr/include/c++/4.5. I also installed zlib library. More specifically, the library cp libz.a is now located at /usr/local/lib.

Comment: Anyways, I finally managed to compile and link gzstream. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

A disgusting method to do this is to execute `gzip -c` on your input file and read the standard output from the `gzip(1)` process using something like `popen(3)`. It'll decompress as little as necessary to fill your process's read requests. But it does require a working installation of `gzip(1)` on the system, which is not ideal, but might be a suitable tradeoff for your application.

Perhaps your application should bundle its own copy of `gzip(1)`? Beware that zlib [has security flaws like everything else](http://cve.mitre.org/cgi-bin/cvename.cgi?name=CAN-2005-2096), and users are not impressed when they have a dozen different applications to update when there is *one* security problem in `zlib`.

You could also write code to incrementally decrypt portions of the input yourself and fill your C++ streams objects with the decrypted data. This route would be more work but wouldn't rely on copying data between processes, so it might be able to run faster, and would probably be less brittle than relying on system-supplied `gzip(1)` executables.

Comment: Correct me if I am wrong. Basically you are saying that my code should start by decompressing the gzipped file, let's say using command system, and delete the decompressed data file after the program is executed. Isn't it?

Comment: [marinara's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7781796/read-input-data-gzipped-file-line-by-line/7782282#7782282) is better than mine but keeps the same "decode what is needed just before it is used" -- I was suggesting that you use `popen(3)` to connect pipes to another process that does the decrypting. There is nothing to _delete_, because the decrypted data is never stored anywhere. The child program would write to its standard output, and you would read it from the `popen(3)` pipe as you need it.